# search value and return adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vlookup

Currently I'm learning about functions in Excel, and although it seems rather basic, I can't seem to find the answer to this exercise I was given anywhere.

[image: my table]

What I'd like to do is use VLOOKUP to find the cell that shows 24000 under "Venta" (C4:C13) and show it's adjacent value under "Vendedor" (B4:B13). Currently I'm trying to use the following function:

```
=VLOOKUP(IF(C4:C13="24000"),B4:C13,FALSE)
```

...but can't seem to get it to work. I simply get the "problem with this formula" error message.

Sorry for the overall lack of knowledge I have. I'm definitely missing something obvious but, hey, we all start somewhere :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` always expects to lookup the value in the first column of an array and will return the matching value in any column to the right of it.

To do what you want, you need to use `INDEX/MATCH`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$4:B$13,MATCH(E12,C$4:C$13,0)),"")
```

Where `E12` contains the value you wish to lookup

For a hard coded value, use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$4:B$13,MATCH(24000,C$4:C$13,0)),"")
```

Comment: And if I wish to not search for the same value contained in another cell, but rather a specific value regardless of it being in something else? (aka search for 24000 but not based off of E12, as E12 is a function itself haha)

Comment: See the edit to my answer, note that the fact that the value of a cell is the result of a formula, does not prevent you from using it in another formula.